# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library)

Tags: php, c++, ubuntu, php-extension

In the past i did create a shared library that now I would like to use it inside a php extension. Is it possible to do that? As I've seen in the `config.m4` file  `PHP_NEW_EXTENSION()` asks for the .cc . The problem is  that i don't want to expose my code. I just want to use the header and the shared library i've creaded in c under ubuntu.For the php extention i did create a : `config.m4, php_c.h and php_c.cc.`

Please help!. THX APPRECIATE
I did put in the config file this:

```
libs=mylib.so; 
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(libs, $EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR, ?? what to add here);
```

I obtain the following:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) '/home/foder/mylib.so'in Unknown on line 0
```

php: symbol lookup error:

```
/usr/php5/20090626+lfs/vehicles.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3CarC1Ei (where vehicles.so) is a php so created with: phpize, ./configure --enable-vehicle make..
```

Comment: You can't just take some random .so and turn it into a PHP extension with a couple lines of config. There's a fair amount of work involved: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021

Answer (score 16):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) '/home/foder/mylib.so'in Unknown on line 0
```

This message means there's no "get_module" function in the ".so".
Make sure the PHP extension source contains the lines:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef COMPILE_DL_MYLIB
ZEND_GET_MODULE(mylib)
#endif
```